# Calendar.getInstance().getTime() returns a wrong date exactly the month number

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I'm facing a problem in the `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`, which returns an illogical month number. like `41/12/2017`.

I tried to use `new Date()` to get the current time, also getting the same bug (illogical month number)

```
startDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).toString());
```

also the same when using new Date()

```
 startDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()).toString());
```

I searched here, but found nothing - just trying to change Calender class and use `new Date()` and getting the same result

I also tried to clean the project, check the emulator date setting, the phone setting bu couldn't  fix the bug.

any help?

Comment: use MM instead of mm

Comment: Months are indexed from 0 not 1 so 10 is November and 11 will be December.

Comment: oh thanks @SachinSarawgi its work for me thanks alote

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks but my problem was that it returned for me unlogic number for months like(56)  and its solved by changing mm to MM

Comment: @maiajam check my below ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/46706545/7666442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **MM** (Months) instead of **mm**(Minute in hour)

```
MM   -->10
MMM  -->Nov
MMMM -->November
```

sample code

```
 startDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).toString());
```

Comment: thanks sorry my reputation low so cant vote up your answer

Answer (score 1):

`mm` stays for minutes in the hour. What you need is `MM`, months in a year.

```
 startDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).toString());
```

you can read more about the pattern [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

In SimpleDateFormat "m" stands for "minute in hour".

If you want to get the month then use following pattern "MM/dd/yyyy".

Also, make sure if you want to use "yyyy" or "YYYY"

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The other Answers are correct about your formatting pattern being incorrect.

Even better, ditch the troublesome old date-time classes. These are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Considering **time zone is crucial** to determining the current date. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. A new day dawns earlier in `Pacific/Auckland` than in `America/Montreal`, for example.

```
ZoneId z = `America/Los_Angeles` ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Let java.time automatically localize to your desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String output = today.format( f ) ;
```

For Java 6 & 7, see the ThreeTen-Backport project. For older Android, see the ThreeTenABP project.

If necessary, convert between the legacy and modern classes by calling new methods added to the old classes in Java 8 or later. If using the back-port see its utility class.